# What are exit_form, next_record are called in technical name in oracle forms.?

Tags: oracleforms

What are exit_form, next_record are called in technical name in oracle forms ?
I don't know the technical name.

Comment: What do you mean by technical name?? Exit_form is a procedure that calls KEY-EXIT trigger and exists the form. Next_record is used to navigate between records in a Datablock, it calls WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger on data block level.

Comment: It is called Built-In procedures.